# Python - Logger over multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I created a module named **log.py** where a function defines how the log will be registered. Here is the atomic code:

```
import logging
import time

def set_up_log():
    """
    Create a logging file.
    """ 
    #
    # Create the parent logger.
    #
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    #
    # Create a file as handler.
    #
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('report\\activity.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(filename)s - %(name)s - %  (levelname)4s - %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    #
    # Start recording.
    #
    logger.info('______ STARTS RECORDING _______')

if __name__=='__main__':
    set_up_log()
```

A second module named **read_file.py** is using this **log.py** to record potential error.

```
import logging
import log
log.set_up_log()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def read_bb_file(input_file):
    """
    Input_file must be the path.
    Open the source_name and read the content. Return the result.
    """
    content = list()
    logger.info('noi')
    try:
        file = open(input_file, 'r')
    except IOError, e:
        logger.error(e)
    else:
        for line in file:
            str = line.rstrip('\n\r')
            content.append(str)
        file.close()
        return content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("begin execution")
    c = read_bb_file('textatraiter.out')
    logger.info("end execution")
```

In the command prompt lauching **read_file.py**, I get this error:

`No handlers could be found for logger "__main__"`

My result in the file is the following

`2014-05-12 13:32:58,690 - log.py - log - INFO - ______ STARTS RECORDING _______`

I read lots of topics here and on Py Doc but it seems I did not understand them properly since I have this error.
I add I would like to keep the log settlement appart in a function and not define it explicitely in my main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 distinct loggers and you're only configuring one.

The first is the one you make in `log.py` and set up correctly. Its name however will be `log`, because you have imported this module from `read_file.py`. 
The second logger, the one you're hoping is the same as the first, is the one you assign to the variable `logger` in  `read_file.py`. Its name will be `__main__` because you're calling this module from the command line. You're not configuring this logger.

What you could do is to add a parameter to `set_up_log` to pass the name of the logger in, e.g.

```
def set_up_log(logname):

    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
```

That way, you will set the handlers and formatters for the correct logging instance.

Organizing your logs in a hierarchy is the way logging was intended to be used by Vinay Sajip, the original author of the module. So your modules would only log to a logging instance with the fully qualified name, as given by `__name__`. Then your application code could set up the loggers, which is what you're trying to accomplish with your `set_up_log` function. You just need to remember to pass it the relevant name, that's all. I found [this reference](http://eric.themoritzfamily.com/learning-python-logging.html) very useful at the time.

Comment: It answers perfectly the question, the second logger is indeed not configured! Thanks, I finally choose the solution on your link by setting not function but a root logger in the log.py file and a logger with parameter '__name__' in read_file.py!

Comment: @Alek_San, then please consider "accepting" the answer, which is the usual way questions on SO get resolved.